# SQL Bulk Upload, Merge and Delete records

Tags: sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlbulkcopy

I am creating an ASP.net web application, which receives a CSV file from the user, uploads the file to the server, bulk copies the data into a `TempHoldingTable`. Then the code calls a stored procedure which contains `Merge` statement to copy the data from the `TempHoldingTable` to the relevant multiple tables. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have multiple `Merge` statements in the stored procedure, I have copied just one below:

```
MERGE Client AS C
USING (SELECT ClientID, Value1, Value2, Value3, Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY ClientID order by Date desc) as Rno 
       FROM TempHoldingTable) AS T ON (C.ClientID = T.ClientID)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND T.Rno = 1
    THEN 
        INSERT(ClientID, Value1, Value2, Value3)
        VALUES(T.ClientID, Value1, Value2, Value3)                      
        OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

The CSV file is uploaded every month so lets suppose the first file was uploaded in Jan 2014 and it has following data:

```
ClientID Value1 Value2 Value3
 111      abc    def    ghi
 222      jkl    mno    pqr
```

The user then uploads second file in Feb 2014 and it has following data:

```
ClientID Value1 Value2 Value3
 111      aaa    bbb    ghi
 222      jkl    mno    pqr
 333      sss    ttt    uuu
```

The Merge routine will update the client table for ClientID 111 because the value1 & value2 have been changed, leave the ClientID 222 as it is and insert a new row for ClientID 333.

My question is if user decides to delete the Feb 2014 file, how can I track and revert the changes which were caused due to Feb 2014 upload so that the Client table contains the same data that it had after Jan 2014 upload.

Please note that this tracking needs to be done for each upload so that whenever a user deletes a file the database reverts to the same position as it was in the previous month.

My second question is how to amend the Merge statement to update values if the ClientID exist and any column has different value then the previous one.

Thanks for your patience with reading all this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if the user where to delete the Feb2014 file, you will have revert back to the Jan 2014 set and then replay the files for March, April, May and so on... Is that correct?

Comment: Users would only be allowed to delete the file in reverse order so if the last file was uploaded in March, then they are allowed to delete March file before deleting the Feb file. When they delete the March file the data would be reverted to how it was when the Feb file was uploaded. And when they delete the Feb file then the data would be reverted to Jan. Once we have the Jan data then user will be allowed to upload the Feb file again, then March and so on.

Comment: How big is your data set?

Comment: Each file can contain 20K to 30K rows and 100+ columns. The data is bulked copied to tempholding table and then move across 8 tables. A lot of rows would contain the same data so that's why I used Merge table so that I don't need to change the data for those records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Q1:
Based on the size of your data, I think setting up a tracking mechanism (`Change tracking /CDC`) will be an overkill (IMO). You could probably setup a process that (before applying the file) pushes the data from each of the 8 tables into another set of tables(versioned dataset) that stores it based on month/year.
If the user decides to delete a particular month file, pull out the previous set from the Versioned Dataset and apply it on the active tables.

Remember to setup a purge process for the versioned dataset though or else it can grow pretty big overtime.

Answer Q2: You could use the `When Matched` clause

```
MERGE Client AS C
USING (SELECT ClientID, Value1, Value2, Value3, Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY ClientID order by Date desc) as Rno 
       FROM TempHoldingTable) AS T ON (C.ClientID = T.ClientID)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET AND T.Rno = 1
    THEN 
        INSERT(ClientID, Value1, Value2, Value3)
        VALUES(T.ClientID, Value1, Value2, Value3)                      
WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE SET C.Value1 = T.Value1
        , C.Value2 = T.Value2
        , C.Value3 = T.Value#3
OUTPUT $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would think a little bit more and speak to colleagues tomorrow, I like the idea of separate versioned table. Out of curiosity, how would the tracking mechanism be implemented, should we decide to go down that route? Please note that we expect to acquire multiple customers so if we have 10 customers then each customer would upload one file each every month (10 files in total). Each customer would have their own data but it will be stored in one database, differentiated by CustomerID. If we acquire 20 Customers then it would be 20 files every month. Please advice.

Comment: I have spoken to colleagues and we would like to go with this route that you recommended. Do you not envisage any issues with this other than purging since the number of files uploaded every month could increase rapidly. Would you provide some info on how to implement tracking mechansim? thanks for your help.

Comment: For SQL server tracking mechanism, you start by reading up the following articles: 1. Change Tracking https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx    2: Change Data capture https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: 'When Matched' statement updates the rows even if value1 or value2 or value3 has not changed, is it possible to only execute update statement if either of the value is different then the existing value?Q2, Do I need to use the primary key and/or T.Rno=1 as in 'When Matched AND T.Rno=1 And C.ClientID=T.ClientID? Or using PK is made redundant by when matched.Thanks